# Add lines with NA values

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data frame like this:

```
   indx country year  death value
1     1   Italy 2000    hiv     1
2     1   Italy 2001    hiv     2
3     1   Italy 2005    hiv     3
4     1   Italy 2000 cancer     4
5     1   Italy 2001 cancer     5
6     1   Italy 2002 cancer     6
7     1   Italy 2003 cancer     7
8     1   Italy 2004 cancer     8
9     1   Italy 2005 cancer     9
10    4  France 2000    hiv    10
11    4  France 2004    hiv    11
12    4  France 2005    hiv    12
13    4  France 2001 cancer    13
14    4  France 2002 cancer    14
15    4  France 2003 cancer    15
16    4  France 2004 cancer    16
17    2   Spain 2000    hiv    17
18    2   Spain 2001    hiv    18
19    2   Spain 2002    hiv    19
20    2   Spain 2003    hiv    20
21    2   Spain 2004    hiv    21
22    2   Spain 2005    hiv    22
23    2   Spain  ...    ...    ...
```

`indx` is a value linked to the `country` (same `country` = same `indx`).

In this example I used only 3 countries (`country`) and 2 disease (`death`), in the original data frame are many more.

I would like to have one row for each country for each disease from 2000 to 2005.

What I would like to get is:

```
    indx  country  year  death  value
1      1    Italy  2000    hiv      1
2      1    Italy  2001    hiv      2
3      1    Italy  2002    hiv     NA
4      1    Italy  2003    hiv     NA
5      1    Italy  2004    hiv     NA
6      1    Italy  2005    hiv      3
7      1    Italy  2000 cancer      4
8      1    Italy  2001 cancer      5
9      1    Italy  2002 cancer      6
10     1    Italy  2003 cancer      7
11     1    Italy  2004 cancer      8
12     1    Italy  2005 cancer      9
13     4   France  2000    hiv     10
14     4   France  2001    hiv     NA
15     4   France  2002    hiv     NA
16     4   France  2003    hiv     NA
17     4   France  2004    hiv     11
18     4   France  2005    hiv     12
19     4   France  2000 cancer     NA
20     4   France  2001 cancer     13
21     4   France  2002 cancer     14
22     4   France  2003 cancer     15
23     4   France  2004 cancer     16
24     4   France  2005 cancer     NA
25     2    Spain  2000    hiv     17
26     2    Spain  2001    hiv     18
27     2    Spain  2002    hiv     19
28     2    Spain  2003    hiv     20
29     2    Spain  2004    hiv     21
30     2    Spain  2005    hiv     22
31     2    Spain  ...     ...     ...
```

I.e. I would like to add lines with `value = NA` at the missing years for each country for each disease.

For example, it lacks data of HIV in Italy between 2002 and 2004 and then I add this lines with `value = NA`.

How can I do that?

For a reproducible example:

```
indx <- c(rep(1, times=9), rep(4, times=7), rep(2, times=6))
country <- c(rep("Italy", times=9), rep("France", times=7), rep("Spain", times=6))
year <- c(2000, 2001, 2005, 2000:2005, 2000, 2004, 2005, 2001:2004, 2000:2005)
death <- c(rep("hiv", times=3), rep("cancer", times=6), rep("hiv", times=3), rep("cancer", times=4), rep("hiv", times=6))
value <- c(1:22)
dfl <- data.frame(indx, country, year, death, value)
```

Comment: I took off the data.table tag since your question isn't about the package or its use. Generally, you shouldn't just add tags to "get attention" from people who follow the tag.

Comment: @Frank Sorry. That was at my suggestion, because the OP was using a data.table as seen by the errors in comments below docendo discimus's answer.

Comment: @lmo Ah ok, good catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using base R, you could do:

```
# setDF(dfl) # run this first if you have a data.table
merge(expand.grid(lapply(dfl[c("country", "death", "year")], unique)), dfl, all.x = TRUE)
```

This first creates all combinations of the unique values in `country`, `death`, and `year` and then merges it to the original data, to add the `values` and where combinations were not in the original data, it adds `NA`s.

In the package `tidyr`, there's a special function that does this for you with a a single command:

```
library(tidyr)
complete(dfl, country, year, death)
```

Comment: Thanks, I try `merge(expand.grid(lapply(dfl[c("country", "death", "year")], unique)), dfl, all.x = TRUE)` in my original big dataframe and I get this error `Error in `[.data.table`(dfl, c("country", "death", "year")) : 
  When i is a data.table (or character vector), x must be keyed (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted) so data.table knows which columns to join to and take advantage of x being sorted. Call setkey(x,...) first, see ?setkey.`..

Comment: Sorry, I use only recently R and sincerely I didn't understand everything that I'm using. I'm still learning. I add the tags. Thank you

Comment: @marielle, please run `setDF(dfl)` first

Comment: Thank you very much, very kind :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a longer base R method. You create two new data.frames, one that contains all combinations of the country, year, and death, and a second that contains an index key.

```
# get data.frame with every combination of country, year, and death
dfNew <- with(df, expand.grid("country"=unique(country), "year"=unique(year),
                              "death"=unique(death)))

# get index key
indexKey <- unique(df[, c("indx", "country")])

# merge these together
dfNew <- merge(indexKey, dfNew, by="country")

# merge onto original data set
dfNew <- merge(df, dfNew, by=c("indx", "country", "year", "death"), all=TRUE)
```

This returns

```
dfNew
   indx country year  death value
1     1   Italy 2000 cancer     4
2     1   Italy 2000    hiv     1
3     1   Italy 2001 cancer     5
4     1   Italy 2001    hiv     2
5     1   Italy 2002 cancer     6
6     1   Italy 2002    hiv    NA
7     1   Italy 2003 cancer     7
8     1   Italy 2003    hiv    NA
9     1   Italy 2004 cancer     8
10    1   Italy 2004    hiv    NA
11    1   Italy 2005 cancer     9
12    1   Italy 2005    hiv     3
13    2   Spain 2000 cancer    NA
14    2   Spain 2000    hiv    17
15    2   Spain 2001 cancer    NA
...
```

---

If df is a data.table, here are the corresponding lines of code:

```
# CJ is a cross-join
setkey(df, country, year, death)
dfNew <- df[CJ(country, year, death, unique=TRUE),
            .(country, year, death, value)]

indexKey <- unique(df[, .(indx, country)])

dfNew <- merge(indexKey, dfNew, by="country")

dfNew <- merge(df, dfNew, by=c("indx", "country", "year", "death"), all=TRUE)
```

---

Note that it rather than using `CJ`, it is also possible to use `expand.grid` as in the data.frame version:

```
dfNew <- df[, expand.grid("country"=unique(country), "year"=unique(year),
                          "death"=unique(death))]
```

Comment: Regarding "If df is a data.table", you can use `CJ(x=x,y=y,z=z, unique=TRUE)` instead of `expand.grid(x=unique(x), y=unique(y), z=unique(z))`. And for the second line there, `unique` has a `by=` argument with data.tables (not sure if that is helpful here, though).

Comment: @Frank True. I'll add this as a possibility / the preferred method. Do you know if there is a performance difference? I'll run a test or two to see.

Answer (score 0):

`tidyr::complete` helps create all combinations of the variables you pass it, but if you have two columns that are identical, it will over-expand or leave `NA`s where you don't want. As a workaround you can use `dplyr` grouping (`df %>% group_by(indx, country) %>% complete(death, year)`) or just merge the two columns into one temporarily:

```
library(tidyr)

       # merge indx and country into a single column so they won't over-expand
df %>% unite(indx_country, indx, country) %>% 
    # fill in missing combinations of new column, death, and year
    complete(indx_country, death, year) %>% 
    # separate indx and country back to how they were
    separate(indx_country, c('indx', 'country'))

# Source: local data frame [36 x 5]
# 
#     indx country  death  year value
#    (chr)   (chr) (fctr) (int) (int)
# 1      1   Italy cancer  2000     4
# 2      1   Italy cancer  2001     5
# 3      1   Italy cancer  2002     6
# 4      1   Italy cancer  2003     7
# 5      1   Italy cancer  2004     8
# 6      1   Italy cancer  2005     9
# 7      1   Italy    hiv  2000     1
# 8      1   Italy    hiv  2001     2
# 9      1   Italy    hiv  2002    NA
# 10     1   Italy    hiv  2003    NA
# ..   ...     ...    ...   ...   ...
```